# Julia: scatter plot with different colors (using either ColorGradient or other continuous color encodings)

Tags: plot, colors, julia, scatter-plot, color-scheme

Very simple question but I'm not very familiar with the way the `ColorGradient` type works so I thought I'd ask here.

Say I have some `x, y` data that I want to plot in the standard way with `scatter(x,y)` and I want to color the dots with their unique colors based on a color map determined by a color gradient (see code below):

```
using Plots
C(g::ColorGradient) = RGB[g[z] for z=LinRange(0,1,30)]
g = :inferno
```

(source: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/ExamplePlots.jl/blob/master/notebooks/cgrad.ipynb)

How would I set up my color gradient object and then use it to map each of my (x,y) pairs to a different one of the colors in the color gradient, using the `scatter()` function?

My guess is something like:

```
x, y = (rand(10), rand(10))
using Plots
C(g::ColorGradient) = RGB[g[z] for z=LinRange(0,1,10)]
g = :blue

scatter(x,y,c=cgrad(g)|> C)
```

I just tried that and it works, but I don't really get why...what is with this `|> C` notation??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest way to get the plot is:

```
using Plots, Colors
scatter(x,y,c=colormap("Blues",10))
```

Another colormap worth mentioning is to have very different colors of points:

```
scatter(x,y,c=distinguishable_colors(10))
```

The `|>` operator is just passing an argument to a function so you can write either `f(x)` or `x |> f`. Consider the example below:

```
julia> f(a,b=5) = a+b;

julia> 7 |> f
12
```